# How do i upgrade ubuntu from 12.04 to 13.10 ?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 13.10

I have been thinking about upgrading to 13.10, the current release of Ubuntu. I am running 12.04 LTS. I was wondering how I would do this without having to back everything up, or do I need to back everything up? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While backing up your files may not be necessary to upgrade your operating system, it is always recommended, as things can and do go wrong during upgrades. Instructions for upgrading your installation can be found on the official Ubuntu help site here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes
You should not skip upgrades (i.e. going directly from 12.04 to 13.10) unless you plan on simply backing up your data and doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10. To avoid having to do a fresh install, you should upgrade to each "in between" version of Ubuntu (i.e. 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04 to 13.10) but still, it is strongly recommended that you back up your data before proceeding with any upgrades.

Comment: EvilBob is right, but more than that, you should have everything backed up pretty much all the time anyway. Backing up for an upgrade shouldn't be anything special.